# Weighted cost function in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to introduce weighting into the following cost function:

```
_cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=_logits, labels=y))
```

But without having to do the softmax cross entropy myself. So I was thinking of breaking the cost calc up into cost1 and cost2 and feeding in a modified version of my logits and y values to each one.

I want to do something like this but not sure what is the correct code:

```
mask=(y==0)
y0 = tf.boolean_mask(y,mask)*y1Weight
```

(This gives the error that mask cannot be scalar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight masks can be computed using `tf.where`. Here is the weighted cost example:

```
batch_size = 100
y1Weight = 0.25
y0Weight = 0.75


_logits = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, 2), stddev=1.))
y = tf.random_uniform(shape=(batch_size,), maxval=2, dtype=tf.int32)

_cost = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=_logits, labels=y)

#Weight mask, the weights for label=0 is y0Weight and for 1 is y1Weight
y_w = tf.where(tf.cast(y, tf.bool), tf.ones((batch_size,))*y0Weight, tf.ones((batch_size,))*y1Weight)

# New weighted cost
cost_w = tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(_cost, y_w))
```

As suggested by @user1761806, the simpler solution would be to use `tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy()` which has allows weighting of the classes.

Comment: Thanks - I also discovered that sparse_softmax_cross_entropy is a wrapper function that utilizes sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits but allows you to provide weights. So i ended up using that.   `lossW = tf.add(1,tf.multiply(tf.cast(tf.equal(y,1),'int32'),1.5))
    _cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(logits=_logits, labels=y,weights=lossW))`

Comment: Shouldn't you switch `y0Weight` and `y1Weight` in `tf.where`? In `tf.where(condition, x, y)`, `x` is for the case `condition` is `True`, that means `label = 1` here.

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate the weighted cost as follows; use a predefined `weights_per_class` tensor with shape `(num_classes, 1)`. For label use [`one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) encoding.

```
# here labels shape should be [batch_size, num_classes] ; obtained using one_hot
_cost = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=_logits, labels=y)

# Here you can define a deterministic weights tensor. 
# weights_per_class = tf.constant(np.array([y0weights, y1weights, ...]))
weights_per_class =tf.random_normal(shape=(num_classes, 1), dtype=tf.float32)

# Use the weights tensor to compute weighted loss
_weighted_cost =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.matmul(_cost, weights_per_class))
```